# open source packages requiring java7

Tags: java, open-source, java-7

As java7 has been around for a while, are there any open source packages using the new java7 constructs? If someone has any pointers to such packages, will appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

http://code.google.com/hosting/search?q=label:Java7 is a list of all Google code projects tagged with the Java7 tag.

Comment: that really doesn't help. the first one on the list is one file. i am looking for big projects like eclipse, jboss, ...